# On premise Docker Central

Tags: docker

We have team of j2ee spring and angular developers.  We are developing small applications in short span.  As of now we don't have luxury to have DevOps team to maintain staging and QA environments.

I am checking feasibility that developer who want to get their application tested can build docker image and float it on on-premise central docker server (At times they work from remote locations as well).  We are in process of CI but it may take some time.
Due to cost pressure we can not use AWS except for production.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you plans on using Docker, you can infact setup a simple build flow which makes lives easier in the long run.

- Use [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com) for building and storing docker images (This saves time for building and also provides a easy way of rolling back shipping and DevOps). It takes few minutes to connect your Github/Bitbucket repository to DockerHub and tell for each branch/tag build an image upon PR merge or push. Also the cost for the service is minimal.
- Use these images for your local environment as well as production environment (Giving guarantee that you refer the correct versions)
- For production use AWS Elastic Beanstalk or AWS ECS (I prefer ECS due to Container Orchestration capabilities) to simplify the Deployments & DevOps where most of the configurations can be done from AWS Web Console). Cost is only for the underlying EC2 instances.
- For Dockerizing your Java application, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ePUiQuaUos) might be helpful to get insights of JVM

Note: Later on you can connect these Dots using your CI environment reducing further efforts